# How to switch all open applications between monitors?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors

When I locked my Windows 7 computer to clean the keyboard, I probably activated some keyboard shortcut by accident. When I logged back in, all open applications had switched monitors (all applications on the left screen had moved to the right screen and vice versa).

What keys could I have pressed that would do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have dual monitors, maybe you pressed <kbd>[image: Windows-Key]</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. This shortcut toggles between various multi-monitor modes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However win+p was most likely not it since the primary screen had not changed. The only thing that had happened was that all applications on the left screen had moved to the right screen and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Windows key + Directional key left or right will cause any active window to snap to the edge of the current monitor then switch to the next monitor if you press again.

Althought this would only explain for the active window.

Are you using a program to help manage multi monitors? Like Display Fusion? Sometimes Diplay Fusion does exactly what you described when i log back in.

edit: actually the windows key + directional key shouldnt do anything if you not signed in